# How do I take care of a cat with a cold?

Tags: cats, medicines

I believe my cat has come down with a cold. I have had a light cold for the last week or so, and unfortunately I think I may have passed it onto her as she started sneezing regularly a few days ago.

What should I do to take care of her? Should I get her some kind of feline cold medicine, or just let her ride the cold out naturally?

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/how-can-i-help-my-cat-with-chronic-congestion-and-sneezing

Answer (score 3):

Cats and dogs cannot get your cold, sneezing can be related to a number of things like dust, something stuck up there (least common reason) or feline upper resp disease (most common) which overtime you'd get eye discharge. Sometimes they just sneeze and it's normal, unless excessive.

If you're concerned then feel free to check with a veterinarian as we can't do much without seeing her in person.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Rebecca, you can't pass a cold to your cat (you can pass on certain eye infections and other stuff but that's another topic). However, if your cat does have a cold it needs to be treated by a vet as what is commonly called a cold among felines can get very, very bad. Cats can lose their eyes for example, but those are of course cases that have been left **untreated** for a long time, so don't panic either :)

If the cat regularly sneezes, or has more eye discharge than usual (especially with red eyes or the pink skin underneath the eyelid (conjunctiva) easily showing), or has trouble breathing, or has, well, snot running out of their nose... Definitely time for the vet.

They will usually prescribe antibiotics that should be given until a day or so after all the symptoms have passed, so get more if necessary.